# Delphi: Process Creation Flags in CreateProcess function

Tags: delphi, flags, createprocess

There are 4 flags that are described usually in articles/examples:

```
 NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS           = $00000020;
  {$EXTERNALSYM NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS}
  IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS             = $00000040;
  {$EXTERNALSYM IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS}
  HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS             = $00000080;
  {$EXTERNALSYM HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS}
  REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS         = $00000100;
  {$EXTERNALSYM REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS}
```

Can I use any of them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684863(v=VS.85).aspx / http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683211(v=VS.85).aspx in that function?

What is the difference between those 2 links?

Why do I get an error in a CreateProcess function: Incompatible types: 'Cardinal' and 'TThreadPriority' if I have and do:

```
var Priority : Cardinal
Priority:=NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS;
CreateProcess(PChar(Path), Pchar(Par), nil, nil, false,
Priority, nil, nil, StartUpInfo, ProcessInfo);
```

What TThreadPriority....

Thanks!

Comment: About you second link; the [GetPriorityClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683211%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function - no you can't; it's written diretctly in the reference `The process's priority class is one of the following values.`

Comment: Do you literally mean all of them (i.e. at the same time), or do you mean any one of them?

Comment: @maxfax - And about your first link and the question; I don't get what you're asking here. In each API function reference is mentioned what you can pass as the parameter, if one of them of such kind of a combination.

Comment: Any of them, what flags can I use except those 4? Thanks!

Comment: @maxfax - You can 'or' one of the priority class flags with any combination of creation flags (except noted in the docs). TThreadPriority is an enumerated type used in TThread.

Comment: There are 6 flags: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683211(v=VS.85).aspx Can I use 6? Or 4 that I mentioned?

Comment: @maxfax - You can use one of the 6. The reason VCL omits 2 is that they are not supported on windows 9x/ME. And the reason this is not mentioned in your link is that those operating systems are not supported by MS anymore.

Comment: @maxfax - There's no error with the code you posted. Unless you're not using CreateProcess in windows.pas. To be sure prefix the unit name: `windows.CreateProcess(..`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of the 6 flags that the documentation of `GetPriorityClass` function mentions. The reason RTL omits 2 of the flags is that they are not supported on Windows 9x/ME (this is in D2007, maybe later versions have those flags).

You can `or` the priority class flag with any combination of process creation flags (except noted in the documentation - the first link you've provided).

`TThreadPriority` is an enumerated type used in `TThread` in 'classes.pas' and is not related in anyway with process creation flags. The code posted in the question does not seem to have any problem (see comments to the question).